# MVC c# mapping to join string values ignoring NULL values

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller, automapper

In my MVC application, I have this problem I am struggling with since yesterday.

Below line of code displays the mapping from entity to model.

```
.ForMember(d => d.AssetModelList, op => op.MapFrom(s => string.Join("; ", s.Assets.Select(a => a.ModelName).ToArray<string>())))
```

Now the problem is `Assests.Count == 6`. So I need to combine all `ModelName` using the semicolon `;` but I also need to ignore when `Asset.ModelName == null`.

Now Under current scenario let's suppose first 4 value of `Asset.count` are `NULL` then outcome of my above code is

> ;;;;model5;model6

Whereas what I need is

> model5;model6

I need to ignore when when `assest.modelname == null`.

Please let me know if the problem is not clear yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.ForMember(d => d.AssetModelList, op => op.MapFrom(s => string.Join("; ", s.Assets.Where(a=> a.ModelName != null).Select(a => a.ModelName).ToArray<string())))
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx :

> The arguments to the **Where**, OrderBy, and Select operators are called lambda expressions, which are fragments of code much like delegates. They allow the standard query operators to be defined individually as methods and strung together using dot notation. Together, these methods form the basis for an extensible query language.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the null values from your collection before you do the join.

```
.ForMember(d => d.AssetModelList,
           op => op.MapFrom(s => string.Join("; ",
                                             s.Assets
                                              // Remove null or whitespace
                                              // Alternatively, a.ModelName != null
                                              .Where(a => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a.ModelName))
                                              .Select(a => a.ModelName)
                                              .ToArray<string>())))
```